# Busybox - How to build a package for opkg

Tags: package-management, busybox

I know how to build a deb package on Ubuntu with the directory structures, the control files and so on for dpkg. Is it the same for opkg?

1. How can I build a package for opkg?
2. Can I produce the package directly on the Busybox or do I need another Linux like Ubuntu?

---

*opkg* 
is working but it has no build option.

I am running on this Busybox:

```
BusyBox v1.23.2 (2017-06-15 11:01:48 CEST) multi-call binary.
BusyBox is copyrighted by many authors between 1998-2012.
Licensed under GPLv2. See source distribution for detailed copyright notices.

Usage: busybox [function [arguments]...]
or: busybox --list
or: function [arguments]...

    BusyBox is a multi-call binary that combines many common Unix
    utilities into a single executable.  Most people will create a
    link to busybox for each function they wish to use and BusyBox
    will act like whatever it was invoked as.

Currently defined functions:
    [, [[, addgroup, adduser, ar, arp, ash, awk, base64, basename, bash, bbconfig, brctl, bunzip2, bzcat, bzip2,
    cat, chattr, chgrp, chmod, chown, chroot, chrt, chvt, clear, cmp, cp, cpio, crond, cut, date, dc, dd,
    deallocvt, delgroup, deluser, devmem, df, diff, dirname, dmesg, dnsdomainname, dos2unix, du, dumpkmap, echo,
    egrep, eject, env, ether-wake, expr, false, fatattr, fbset, fbsplash, fdisk, fgrep, find, flock, fstrim,
    getopt, getty, grep, groups, gunzip, gzip, hd, head, hexdump, hostname, id, ifconfig, ifdown, ifup, inetd,
    inotifyd, insmod, ionice, iostat, ip, kbd_mode, klogd, less, ln, loadfont, loadkmap, logger, logname, logread,
    losetup, ls, lsattr, lsmod, lsof, lspci, lsusb, lzcat, md5sum, microcom, mkdir, mkdosfs, mkfifo, mkfs.vfat,
    mknod, mkswap, mktemp, modinfo, modprobe, more, mount, mpstat, mv, nameif, nbd-client, nc, netstat, nice,
    nmeter, nohup, nslookup, ntpd, od, openvt, patch, pidof, powertop, printf, pwd, rdate, rdev, readahead,
    readlink, readprofile, realpath, renice, reset, rm, rmdir, rmmod, route, run-parts, sed, sendmail, seq,
    setconsole, setfont, setkeycodes, setlogcons, setserial, setsid, sh, sha1sum, sha256sum, sha3sum, sha512sum,
    showkey, shuf, sleep, smemcap, sort, start-stop-daemon, strings, stty, sulogin, swapoff, swapon, switch_root,
    sync, syslogd, tail, tar, taskset, tee, telnet, telnetd, test, tftp, time, timeout, touch, tr, true, tty,
    tunctl, tune2fs, udhcpc, umount, uname, uniq, unix2dos, unlink, unlzma, unxz, unzip, users, usleep, uudecode,
    uuencode, vconfig, vi, volname, wc, wget, which, who, whoami, whois, xargs, xzcat, yes, zcat
```

Comment: This question would be clearer if you weren't making the "Oh, my operating system/terminal/machine is Busybox." error.  What you apparently _actually_ want to do is make a package that can then be installed by `opkg`, your system's package manager.

Comment: Ok, this is my Question.

Answer (score 1):

Busybox is a set of simple tools, and it doesn't have a package management facility. You should specify what system you run your busybox on and it might contain one.